# Want the left div to match size with the content div even if the left div have more data

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am building a layout for my website for which I am using css-grid. I am open to use flexbox too if it solves my purpose. I have a header, footer, left-widget, right-widget and main section(div). I want the layout to take up the entire screen. If the main section expands based on its contents I want left and right widget to match its size.

P.S - Left and right widget can have more content than the main content in that case i want a scrollbar in left and right widget

I have tried this using css-grid but the left right and main section is taking the size of the largest div.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'left main right' 'footer footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 3vh minmax(93vh, auto) 3vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.leftWidget {
  grid-area: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

.rightWidget {
  grid-area: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=header>

  </div>
  <div class=leftWidget>

  </div>
  <div class=main>

  </div>
  <div class=rightWidget>

  </div>
  <div class=footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/an68gbdm/ matches your requirements?

Comment: @kukkuz - No its close but it doesn't match the exact requirement. I don't want the main section to have a scrollbar. I want the entire layout to expand based on the main section. The entire page will get a scroll-bar and the left and right widget will expand based on the size of main. Even if the left and right have more contents they will have their individual scrollbar but their height will match the main section. Is it possible?

Comment: use some positioning here... see https://jsfiddle.net/x3kq97w6/ is this working fine?

Comment: could you please upvote / accept the answer(s) below and thereby close the question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kukkuz - I have followed your previously suggested fiddle. It worked fine for me. Thank you. Maybe you deleted the fiddle but that is the one i followed. I am posting the code here again if anyone need in the future. I have done some basic tweaking to match my need.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'left main right' 'footer footer footer';
    grid-template-rows: minmax(60px,4vh) 1fr minmax(40px,3vh);
    grid-template-columns: minmax(150px,12vw) minmax(700px,1fr) minmax(200px,15vw);
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: blue;
  }

  .leftWidget {
    grid-area: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .rightWidget {
    grid-area: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: green;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .main {
    grid-area: main;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: yellow;
  }

  .footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: blue;
  }
```

Code credit - @kukkuz

Comment: from my last comment to question: https://jsfiddle.net/x3kq97w6/ - the content area will determine the height of the second row... if you want this behaviour after the height of content has exceeded viewport height, add `height: 100vh` to the *grid container*... and good to know you have found a working solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make these changes to your code:

- use auto (instead of 93vh) for the second row so that it occupies the space of its contents,
- and instead of 3vh height for the *header* and *footer*, you can use fixed height (say 3em),
- add a `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` definition for 3 equal columns which allows the sidebars and the content area take equal widths.

See demo below contents in the sidebars less that that of the content area - this works because the content area has more height:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 
                       'left main right' 
                       'footer footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 3em auto 3em; /* middle row occupies space of its contents */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 equal columns */
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.leftWidget {
  grid-area: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

.rightWidget {
  grid-area: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=header>Header</div>
  <div class=leftWidget>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here
  </div>
  <div class=main>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here 
  </div>
  <div class=rightWidget>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here
  </div>
  <div class=footer>Footer</div>
</div>
```

---

To ensure that the height of the middle row is defined by the `main` element, you can use and extra wrapper inside the sidebars and use *absolute positioning* - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 
                       'left main right' 
                       'footer footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 3em auto 3em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 equal columns */
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.leftWidget {
  grid-area: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.rightWidget {
  grid-area: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.leftWidget > div,
.rightWidget > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="leftWidget">
    <div>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here
  </div>
  <div class="rightWidget">
    <div>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to have a min-height to the *grid container* and have the above effect only after that, just add `height: 100vh` to the container:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 
                       'left main right' 
                       'footer footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 3em auto 3em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 equal columns */
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.leftWidget {
  grid-area: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.rightWidget {
  grid-area: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.leftWidget > div,
.rightWidget > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="leftWidget">
    <div>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here
  </div>
  <div class="rightWidget">
    <div>
    Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here Lorel ipsum some text here 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```